# How to use Levene's test on a data frame in R

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame with two columns, height (in inches) and sex (Male or Female) and I want to run levene's test to see if the variance is the same for Male and Female height. How would I do this?

I've read a few other questions here but none of them seem to address running a test from a data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually very easy. Assuming your data is in `data` and the columns are `height` and `sex`:

```
# load leveneTest function
library(car)
# run the levene test centered around the mean
leveneTest(data$height, data$sex, center=mean)
```

Comment: or as suggested by the help page `with(data,leveneTest(height,sex, ...))`